# Variable declaration between function name and first curly brace

Tags: c, obfuscation

I am reading an article about **code obfuscation** in C, and one of the examples declares the main function as:

```
int main(c,v) char *v; int c;{...}
```

I've never saw something like this, `v` and `c` are global variables?

The full example is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define THIS printf(
#define IS "%s\n"
#define OBFUSCATION ,v);

int main(c, v) char *v; int c; {
   int a = 0; char f[32];
   switch (c) {
      case 0:
         THIS IS OBFUSCATION
         break;
      case 34123:
         for (a = 0; a < 13; a++) { f[a] = v[a*2+1];};
         main(0,f);
         break;
      default:
         main(34123,"@h3eglhl1o. >w%o#rtlwdl!S\0m");
         break;
      }
}
```

The article: [brandonparker.net](http://www.brandonparker.net/code_obf.php) **(No longer works)**, but can be found [in web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20121108041752/http://www.brandonparker.net/code_obf.php)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the old style function definition

```
void foo(a,b)
int a;
float b;
{
// body
}
```

is same as

```
void foo(int a, float b)
{
// body
}
```

Your case is same as `int main(int c,char *v){...}` But it's not correct.

The correct syntax is : `int main(int c, char **v){...}`

Or, `int main(int c, char *v[]){...}`

EDIT : Remember in `main()` , `v` should be `char**` not the `char*` as you have written.

I think it's `K & R` C style.

Comment: So is the same that int main(int c, char* v)?

Comment: @algui91 - yes. This is `K & R C`

Answer (score 7):

It is a pre-ANSI C syntax for function declaration. We don't use it anymore. It is the same as:

```
int main(int c, char *v)
```