# Why variables are declared outside brackets

Tags: c

Below is a C function. I did not understand the declaration of variable after function name. As in the text book after function name it should start with curly bracket. But here without curly bracket it declares 3 variables. Could anyone tell me : are  those variables local to function  and why they are not inside curly bracket.

```
static long CheckBytes ( kind, byt, typ )
/*********************************************************************/
  long               kind             ;
  long               byt              ;
  long               typ              ;
{
  long               byte             ;

  byte = 0 ;
  switch ( typ ) {
    case 1 :
      if ( kind == 1 ) {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 16 ) byte = byt / 4 ;
      }
      else {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 16 ) byte = byt / 2 ;
      }
      break ;
    case 2 :
      if ( kind == 2 ) {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 32 ) byte = byt ;
      }
      else {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 32 ) byte = byt ;
      }
      break ;
    case 3 :
      if ( kind == 1 ) {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 16 ) byte = byt / 4 ;
      }
      else {
        if ( byt >= 1 && byt <= 16 ) byte = byt / 2 ;
      }
      break ;
  }

  return ( byte ) ;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789450/variable-declaration-between-function-name-and-first-curly-brace) answer

Comment: This is very old style. It is equivalent to 'static long CheckBytes(long kind, long byt, long typ) { //...}'

Answer (score 3):

It is the old way of defining functions. Basically

```
static long CheckBytes(kind,byt,typ)
  long kind;
  long byt;
  long typ;
{
```

is the same as

```
static long CheckBytes(long kind,long byt, long typ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

This function is defined using the original Kernighan and Ritchie syntax. It is considered old fashioned and not used much anymore. Prefer the newer style (aka *ANSI style*) syntax introduced with C89:

```
static long CheckBytes(
     long               kind,
     long               byt,
     long               typ) { ,,,
```